# Why BeautifulSoup and lxml don't work?

Tags: python, request, html-parsing, response

I'm using `mechanize` library to log in website. I checked, it works well. But problem is i can't use `response.read()` with `BeautifulSoup` and 'lxml'.

```
#BeautifulSoup
response = browser.open(url)
source = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)  #source.txt doesn't work either
for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'someClass'}):
    some_list.add(link)
```

This doesn't work, actually doesn't find any tag. It works well when i use `requests.get(url)`.

```
#lxml->html
response = browser.open(url)
source = response.read()
tree = html.fromstring(source)  #souce.txt doesn't work either
print tree.text
like_pages = buyers = tree.xpath('//a[@class="UFINoWrap"]')  #/text() doesn't work either
print like_pages
```

Doesn't print anything. I know it has problem with return type of `response`, since it works well with `requests.open()`. What could i do? Could you, please, provide sample code where `response.read()` used in html parsing?

By the way, what is difference between `response` and `requests` objects?

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. It is because `mechanize.browser` is emulated browser, and it gets only raw html. The page i wanted to scrape adds class to tag with help of JavaScript, so those classes were not on raw html. Best option is to use webdriver. I used Selenium for Python. Here is code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.http.phishy-userpass-length', 255)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

driver.get(url)
list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="someClass"]')
```

*Note: You need to have Firefox installed. Or you can choose another profile according to browser you want to use.*

---

> A request is what a web client sends to a server, with details about what URL the client wants, what http verb to use (get / post, etc), and if you are submitting a form the request typically contains the data you put in the form.
>   A response is what a web server sends back in reply to a request from a client. The response has a status code which indicates if the request was successful (code 200 usually if there were no problems, or an error code like 404 or 500). The response usually contains data, like the html in a page, or the binary data in a jpeg. The response also has headers that give more information about what data is in the response (e.g. the "Content-Type" header which says what format the data is in).

Quote from @davidbuxton's answer on this **[link](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3baft8/why_beautifulsoup_and_lxml_dont_work/)**.

**Good luck!**